# Bash Script Executing C Application With Changing Parameter

Tags: c, bash

I have a C application called Test. Test takes in a single int parameter. I want to run Test with many different parameters, so I made the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..5}
do
    ./Test "$i" 
done
```

However, this executes `./Test "$i"` and not `./Test 0, ./Test 1` etc. Changing it to `./Test $i` simply executes `./Test $i` 5 times.What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem is wrong. Replace test with /bin/echo and see that it works. There shall be some other problem, probably in `./Test` itself.

Comment: I think you're right. /bin/echo prints out the correct values of i: 0 to 5. I'll double check the C program. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `seq 0 5`
do
    ./Test $i 
done
```

To create sequences in bash you can use `seq`, which has an advantage of working in any bourne-compatible shell (that is, `seq` works *everywhere* because it's an external program, it's the `for` loop that becomes more portable).

Yes, it makes no difference with respect to `./Test` invocation, but it provides a *respectful* reason to procrastinate before fixing `./Test`.

Comment: You can use `{}` just as well. What's the point of advising to try this and that if you don't understand what's wrong? (It would help if you had at least an *idea* on what's wrong. Not necessary correct idea, just any idea, without "try random things doing the same" nonsense).

Comment: Same version here, works as *documented* (it's "Brace Expansion", it was there for *years*. Just tried it in 3.2.48 and it works too)

Comment: You're right. I'm wrong. Sorry, still I'd consider using seq as it also works with other shells (dash, for example).

Comment: The answer is better now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in {0..5}
do
    ./Test " $i" 
done
```

Or

```
for i in {1..5}; do exec "./Test $i" ; done
```

Comment: That simply executes `./Test $i` 5 times, the value of `i` is still not being replaced..

Comment: @JayMahendru gave you two solutions... you missed the space